# Karma ERROR [config]: Invalid config file

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, aurelia

I am trying to use Karma + Jasmine for unit testing my Aurelia (+ Webpack + TypeScript) app. I tried to use the testing boilerplate that came with [the skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases/tag/1.0.3).

On the skeleton project, following npm script runs perfectly:

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js"
```

But when I tried the same on my project, it throws error (without further stacktrace):

```
DEBUG [config]: Loading config C:\Path\to\my\Website\test\karma.conf.js
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
```

It does not provide any other information about why the configuration is invalid.

Below is the `karma.conf.js` that came with the skeleton:

```
"use strict";
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
    basePath: __dirname,

    /*
     * Frameworks to use
     *
     * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     */
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [ ],

    /*
     * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
     *
     * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.js
     */
    files: [
      { pattern: 'spec-bundle.js', watched: false },
    ],

    /*
     * preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
     * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
     */
    preprocessors: {
      'spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: require('../webpack.config'),

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [{
        type: 'json',
        subdir: '.', 
        file: 'coverage-final.json'
      }]
    },

    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      src: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage/coverage-final.json'),
      reports: {
        html: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage/')
      },
      timeoutNotCreated: 1000,
      timeoutNoMoreFiles: 1000
    },

    // Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    webpackServer: { noInfo: true},

    /*
     * test results reporter to use
     *
     * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
     * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
     */
    reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage', 'karma-remap-istanbul' ],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    /*
     * level of logging
     * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
     */
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,

    /*
     * start these browsers
     * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     */
    browsers: [
      'Chrome',
      // TODO: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-electron
    ],

    /*
     * Continuous Integration mode
     * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
     */
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

To isolate the issue, I also tried to start generating a new `karma.conf.js` at my website root, with `karma init`, and I faced exactly the same error with `karma start`. Below is the config file, thus generated:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Dec 14 2016 07:50:15 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './test/**/*Spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

I am using the following versions of the npm packages:

```
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
"typescript": "2.1.1",
"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
```

Please suggest how this can be resolved or at least have more (debug) information to investigate.

**Update:** Got the below stacktrace after `rimraf`ing the `node_modules` and reinstalling the packages:

```
DEBUG [config]: Loading config C:\Path\to\my\Website\test\karma.conf.js
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'dir1'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'dir2'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'dir3'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'lang1'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'dir4'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'lang2'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'maps'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'valueConverters'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'views'. (2688)
    at getOutput (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:312:17)
    at C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:343:18
    at Object.compile (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:476:19)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:406:44)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:409:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.parseConfig (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\karma\lib\config.js:342:22)
    at new Server (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:56:20)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\karma\lib\cli.js:280:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Path\to\my\Website\node_modules\karma\bin\karma:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Comment: Invalid config file generally points out what is invalid about the file.  Seems to be something missing from the output...

Comment: @PWKad Is there anyway to have any verbose log of the output, as that was all what I have on console.

Comment: If it helps someone, your suggestion to delete and restore packages resolved the issue for me. I don't understand root cause, but it appears to be a one-off situation and perhaps will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Having had the same issue this morning, I found that changing the ts-node version resolved this issue. I can reproduce this issue without any configuration changes with ts-node@3.2.0, but the entire build works fine with ts-node@3.1.0, so it seems there's a breaking change in that.